# Laravel Eloquent query for left join

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I have two tables available. 1) Users 2) Friendships. Following is the table structure:

1. Users Table have following columns

- id
- email
- dob
- password
- first_name
- last_name
- username
- gender
- phone
- country

2. Friendships table have following columns

- id
- sender_id
- recipent_id
- status
- created_at
- updated_at

Now I want to retrieve data from the "**users**" table using the "**sender_id**," which is the same as the "**id**" in the "**users**" table.

I'm using the left join to perform the required query as follow:

```
public function show_friend_request(){

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        **//Below query will get the userID's of people who have sent the request to current user.**

        $get_friend_requests = DB::table('friendships')->where('recipient_id',$user_id)
        ->where('status','pending')->get(['sender_id'])->first()->sender_id;
      
        $show_friend_request_Data = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('friendships', 'sender_id', '=', $get_friend_requests)
        ->get();

       return $show_friend_request_Data ;
     
    }
```

But when i executed the above code i'm getting the following error:

```
    Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.sender_id' in 'on clause' 
select * from `users` left join `friendships` on `users`.`sender_id` = `63b8760f-826b-4c1c-aea9-23f1dff148db`
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is:

```
   $show_friend_request_Data = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('friendships', 'friendships.sender_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('users.id', '=', $get_friend_requests)
    ->get();
```

I also suggest you to think of how to optimise the whole query to only 1 request and also how to get multiple friend requests at the time. Because now you're only getting the first friend pending friend request ;)

Comment: One more thing the query to obtain the ID of user is following :

        $get_friend_requests = DB::table('friendships')->where('recipient_id', $user_id)->where('status', 'pending')->get(['sender_id'])->first()->sender_id;


what if i want to obtain multiple id's for instance:

        $get_friend_requests = DB::table('friendships')->where('recipient_id', $user_id)->where('status', 'pending')->get(['sender_id']);


I will get the user ID's in  json format. So how can i get them in text format so that i can write i function to input that id and retrieve all the friend request data?

Comment: then you could use whereIn('users.id', implode($get_friend_requests)) function